# How to use MATLAB to numerically solve equation with unknown embedded in integral?

Tags: matlab, equation, integral

I've been trying to use MATLAB to solve equations like this:

> B = alpha*Y0*sqrt(epsilon)/(pi*ln(b/a)*sqrt(epsilon_t))*integral from
>   0 to pi of
>   (2*sinint(k0*sqrt(epsilon*(a^2+b^2-2abcos(theta))-sinint(2*k0*sqrt(epsilon)*a*sin(theta/2))-sinint(2*k0*sqrt(epsilon)*b*sin(theta/2)))
>   with regard to theta

Where *epsilon* is the unknown.

I know how to symbolically solve equations with unknown embedded in an integral by using `int()` and `solve()`, but using the symbolic integrator `int()` takes too long for equations this complicated. When I try to use `quad()`, `quadl()` and `quadgk()`, I have trouble dealing with how the unknown is embedded in the integral.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34241-integral-equation-solver

Comment: Are all of the other constants defined above? (i.e. alpha, Y0, etc.)

Comment: Those constants are just arbitrary constants for the purposes of calculation, only epsilon is the unknown. theta is just the integration variable (like dx,dy,dz, etc)

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing gets complicated real fast. Although it is possible to do it all in a single inline equation, I would advise you to split it up into multiple nested functions, if only for readability.

The best example of why readability is important: you have a bracketing problem in the eqution you posted; there's not enough closing brackets, so I can't be entirely sure what the equation looks like in mathematical notation :)

Anyway, here's one way to do it with the version I --think-- you meant:

```
function test

    % some random values for testing    

    Y0 = rand;
    b  = rand;
    a  = rand;
    k0 = rand;
    alpha     = rand;
    epsilon_t = rand;

    % D is your B
    D = -0.015;

    % define SIMPLE anonymous function 
    Bb = @(ep) F(ep).*main_integral(ep) - D;

    % aaaand...solve it!
    sol = fsolve(Bb, 1)

    % The anonymous function above is only simple, because of these: 

    % the main integral    
    function val = main_integral(epsilon)

        % we need for loop through epsilon, due to how quad(gk) solves things
        val = zeros(size(epsilon));
        for ii = 1:numel(epsilon)

            ep = epsilon(ii);

            % NOTE how the sinint's all have a different function as argument:
            val(ii) = quadgk(@(th)...
                2*sinint(A(ep,th)) - sinint(B(ep,th)) - sinint(C(ep,th)), ...
                0, pi);            
        end

    end

    % factor in front of integral
    function f = F(epsilon)        
        f = alpha*Y0*sqrt(epsilon)./(pi*log(b/a)*sqrt(epsilon_t)); end

    % first sinint argument
    function val = A(epsilon, theta)
        val = k0*sqrt(epsilon*(a^2+b^2-2*a*b*cos(theta))); end

    % second sinint argument
    function val = B(epsilon, theta)
        val = 2*k0*sqrt(epsilon)*a*sin(theta/2); end

    % third sinint argument
    function val = C(epsilon, theta)
        val = 2*k0*sqrt(epsilon)*b*sin(theta/2); end    

end
```

The solution above will still be quite slow, but I think that's pretty normal for integrals this complicated.

I don't think implementing your own `sinint` will help much, as most of the speed loss is due to the for loops with non-builtin functions...If it's speed you want, I'd go for a MEX implementation with your own Gauss-Kronrod adaptive quadrature routine.